# How can one make an analog voltage memory circuit?

Tags: voltage, analog, memory

I am looking for a circuit that can, on input, remember a certain voltage and output that voltage indefinitely even after the input has been taken away. The circuit should not change its output until a new input has been provided.

I understand that such a circuit can be made by digitally sampling the input up to some arbitrary resolution, but I would like to know if a simple analog solution is possible.

I would also like to keep this solution purely electronic, as I can also envisage a mechanical solution in which a feedback circuit mehanically controls a potentiometer.

Finally, I would ideally not like the circuit to rely on the passive stability of any floating inputs. The circuit should be stable for at least hours.

Comment: Simply put, it doesn't exist and I know I'm sticking my neck out so, if anyone has a good answer to this I'm ready with the upvote button LOL.

Comment: The best way to do this is digitally (convert A->D, store, convert D->A). It's **possible** to do this in an analog fashion, but it will be expensive, have limited accuracy and prone to errors from humidity etc.

Comment: This circuit is called "sample-and-hold".  Stability for hours will be difficult.

Comment: Single polarity? Can I use a relay?  Aluminum electrolytics hold charge for a long time... in a temperature controlled box?    Why not digital?

Comment: I suppose a Hall effect sensor could be used to produce a voltage stored as the strength of a magnetic field. The input voltage can go to an electromagnet. To set the voltage heat the magnet beyond the Currie temperature and then let it cool. (I'm not sure this will work... I'm modeling it in my head as an analog version of core memory)

Comment: @Andyaka See my comment on Sphero's answer. I think the ISD 256 ANALOG levels in a digital bit may qualify for your upvote :-) - even if it's only a comment.

Comment: @user2640461 - See my comment on Sphero's answer. This system stores analog levels and reads them back non-destructively. Because it is intended to have analog output as part of a speech stream you cannot easily access any one storage location and read it BUT if you looked aat an analog output stream read from such a device each locations contents could easily be determined.

Answer (score 13):

This is not a practical answer unless you happen to work for a company with the resources of, say, Intersil, but the technology exists to make this work. Consider the [ISL21080](http://www.intersil.com/content/dam/Intersil/documents/isl2/isl21080.pdf) type references which hold charge, hopefully for the life of the equipment they're installed into, based on a tiny capacitance isolated by quantum tunneling effects. Provided they don't get too much in the way of X-rays etc. they'll remain pretty stable for **years**. See, for example, [this application note](http://www.intersil.com/content/dam/Intersil/documents/an15/an1533.pdf).

[image]

I might add this kind of thing gives me the willies.

For an ordinary application, digital is most likely the way to go.

Comment: This is how cheap analog voice recorders and greeting cards work. Example: http://www.kowatec.com/prod/ap/doc/apr6016-v13.pdf

Comment: @phil: No, it's not.  From your link: "A maximum of
30K bits of digital data can be stored."  It also mentiond 256 signal levels -- that's discrete storage, not analog.

Comment: Well I guess all memory is analog storage to some degree.  But the key point is that the analog voice recorder IC doesn't even guarantee the signal stays in the same bucket, except for a few "digital-approved" sectors.  So it's not holding the value very well.

Comment: @BenVoigt The ISD speech recorder ICs stored 256 analog levels in a "charge well" originally intended to be a digital bit store. That's analog storage in a notionally digital bit.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon: Right, all storage is analog.  To recap what you already know, for other readers: It correctly stores something digitally as long as the error is small enough not to cross a decoder threshold (or remain recoverable after error correction, in the case of better coding schemes).  The digital system is usually designed to be tolerant of large analog errors, which would render performance for storage of analog signals quite poor.

Comment: @BenVoigt - I didn't explain that clearly enough. In the case of ISD they took a charge well in a technology ORIGINALLY intended to be used as a 1 or 0 bit store and instead in each "1 digital bit" charge well they stored incremental charges in 256 levels (they may use a companding law). They then sensed the amount of charge stored (by specific means unknown to me) and obtained a 256 analog level / 8 bit equivalent word. By doing this they increased the amount of available speech memory by a factor of 8 as what would usually take 8 bits (2^8 = 256) was able to be stored in a single bit space.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon The gate can hold only discrete electrons, so the 'analog' voltage is limited to around 25 bits resolution for a 10pF-ish gate and 1V-ish voltage. ;-)

Comment: @SpehroPefhany - 25 **bits** would be nice :-). ISD manage 8 bits or 256 levels equivalent.

Answer (score 4):

EEPROM technology split into two branches in the early 1980s - one thin oxide (FLOTOX) with Intel and Seeq and the other thick oxide (Xicor).  In the early days, there were weaknesses to both routes.  Thin oxide leaked charge and thick oxide was inherently impossible to scale.  There were other issues, but they don't apply here.

Given the thick oxide didn't "leak" electrons, I asked the designers at Xicor about the theoretical resolution of a single thick oxide cell if we discounted the limitations of the sense amps, and they said it could approach 1ppm (roughly 20 bits).  Since I was also associated with LTC, which was one of the leaders in precision voltage references that were inherently power hungry, that led me to think a single EEPROM cell could be adapted to be a high precision and very low power voltage reference.  My longer term thinking was this technology could be developed further for use in AI and used in conjunction with n fan-out non-blocking, reconfigurable non-volatile multiplexers.

Fast forward about 15 years - Xicor ended up developing such a device and then subsequently was acquired by Intersil.   Given the inability to scale, the longer term vision is probably not practical.  However, other technologies can enable the vision when combined with a software software reconfigurable mux.

Answer (score 2):

This device does exist although it's not readily available in single unit quantities, its output amplifiers will get in the way and it's very non-linear.

It is a Floating Gate MOSFET, used in Flash memory, EEPRom and the ilk.  The programming charge can be variable though somewhat unpredictable as the FN tunnelling (Fowler Nordheim) will be variable across the die.  While non-linear it is a proportional effect so you could imagine designing a circuit that linearized the programming effect (of Vth shift).  It will be stable over weeks to months so it meets the requirements of hours that you say you'd need.

But a lot depends upon the specifications that you need, how much drift is acceptable etc.

Just to be clear here, I am talking about the individual device/transistor not the complete component as the support circuits of a Flash will prevent you from operating the cells in this way.

Here are 3 references from an [EDN](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/124946/how-can-one-make-an-analog-voltage-memory-circuit) article talking about a company called GTronix which was acquired by National Semi (now TI).

Lee, BW, BJ Sheu, and H Yang, “Analog floating-gate synapses for general-purpose VLSI neural computation,” IEEE Transactions on Circuits and Systems, Volume 38, Issue 6, June 1991, pg 654.

Fujita, O, and Y Amemiya, “A floating-gate analog memory device for neural networks,” IEEE Transactions on Electron Devices, Volume 40, Issue 11, November 1993, pg 2029.

Smith, PD, M Kucic, and P Hasler, “Accurate programming of analog floating-gate arrays,” IEEE International Symposium on Circuits and Systems, Volume 5, May 2002, pg V-489.

THere is another class of device that is called a MNOS transistor (Metal Nitride Oxide Semiconductor) in which tehere are two dielectrics in the gate, one of which is Si3N4 which has a lot of traps. This device operates very similarly to the flash cell above.

Answer (score 1):

I left a comment and thought about it for a minute and will say with hopeful certainty that it does not exist - some drift away from the "sampled" voltage is not only likely but a certainty. Resolution is critical it seems, (as implied in your question) and this is why I say it doesn't exist. Noise is another factor that will reduce the fidelity of what you have sampled.

Even a digital system (with more than enough resolution) will be inaccurate in reproducing the voltage you apparently "stored". Anything taken to limits will be a problem. The potentiometer idea (suggested in the question) is also flawed because it relies on the reference voltage across its terminals being kept (or reproduced) - you cannot know how these things minutely drift but, again, it's all down to accepting an error or rejecting that error.

Comment: Minute drift and noise is to be expected in all circuits, and I am not concerned with extremely precise reproduction, just something that will be a least slightly more stable than a free floating input. I would be satisfied with a digital memory solution, but was wondering if a more direct solution existed. Thanks for the input.

Comment: @user2640461  I have a number of these still - I used to make "talking" disability aids using these as the speech store. 8 bits/256 levels stored as analog level in a usually-digital bit. 

http://studyelins.blogspot.com/2012/11/voice-recorder-with-isd-2590.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the ISD chips work this way. In fact an inventor in the 1990s claimed to have found a way to store an entire 1 hour movie in a 16MB analog memory chip.

The problem turned out to be (Yup you guessed it!) voltage drift over time.
Sure the chip would store your movie just fine for a day, possibly two but even powered eventually it would degrade beyond use because the individual values stored could not be recovered without referring to the original file.
I actually looked into using this to store SSTV signals but ran into the same problem, conventional floppy disks or even VHS tape were far more reliable.

Comment: Interesting hack: I came up with this while tinkering with the idea of using ZnS glow in the dark material as a way to store data.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the best I can do that approaches those (unrealistic) requirements:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqwJFu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The "sample" switch should be a mechanical relay in which the contacts are truly disconnected from the input. This will eliminate parasitic currents that will cause drift if using a semiconductor switch. However, in practice, you will like use a high-performance analog switch to keep the design solid-state.                                                                                         You want a switch with a very high impedance in the off state. Ironically, the on-state resistance isn't important. You also want the lowest leakage/bias currents possible for long term stability.

Now for the amplifier treatment. You're going to want an ideal amplifier; one that comes from a first year analog design textbook. Unfortunately, Digikey has been out of stock of those for some time now. So the best substitute  you can do shall be as close as possible to these specs for long term stability:

- Infinite open loop gain
- 0pA input bias current
- 0pA input offset current
- infinite CMRR
- 0ppm/degC temperature coefficient
- 0pV input offset voltage

There may other specs I'm missing but the point is these non-idealities compromise the long-term performance (and short-term if the specs are poor enough). Sure, you can get fancy and do some tricks to mitigate these effects at the expense of circuit simplicity, but you can't eliminate them and the output will still drift.

C1 ideally will have no leakage current. In reality, this will be a high-quality film capacitor of relatively large value as to not be so influenced by the amplifier parasitics.

Then, put the whole circuit in a iso-thermically controlled crucible to meet temperature drift performance.